# Store Keepass files inside Truecrypt container

Tags: security, encryption, passwords, truecrypt, keepass

Do you recommend storing Keepass files inside Truecrypt or is it a bit overkill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Keepass containers are encrypted themselves then putting them inside an encrypted container afterwards "for added security" is most definitely overkill.

Keepass encrypts using current cryptographic techniques ([AES](http://keepass.info/help/base/faq_tech.html#encryptionalgo)) but can be extended to use other encryption methods via [plugins](http://keepass.info/plugins.html).

The only real reasons to put a Keepass file inside a Truecrypt  container would be to either hide the fact that you have a Keepass file or to increase the amount of time it takes to get a to your data.  Any company/agency with the time and resources to break a Keepass file will also have the time and resources to break the Truecrypt container as well but will take a bit longer, you are not really adding any extra security beyond making it harder (longer) to crack.